# facebook graph api 2.5 friendLists members empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am calling 
 2.5/firiend_list_id?fields=members

I always get an empty list back and not the members.

Does this still exist? Is there a way to get members of a friendList

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to get members of a friend list

Answer (score 0):

It will only return friends that are also using the app.

If you want to let your people tag their friends in stories that they publish to Facebook using your App, you can use the /me/taggable_friends API. Use of this endpoint requires review by Facebook and should only be used for the case where you're rendering a list of friends in order to let the user tag them in a post.